# Handling duplicate entries in shaded (uber/fat) jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar, classloader, gradle-shadow-plugin

I created a jar file, created from multiple jars (I used [Gradle Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin in this case).

It turned out that the file contains duplicate files in `/META-INF`. Most of them are multiple `license.txt` from the original jar files, but some of them are Spring factories, which I'm interested in.

This behaviour seems common when using various fatjar-like tools with Maven or Gradle, and it looks like it is not prohibited by any means.

I've checked that `java.lang.ClassLoader#getResources` will return these entries as a list of the same URLs, eg.:

- `jar:file:/C:/temp/myJar.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories`
- `jar:file:/C:/temp/myJar.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories`

so once I get the URL, there's no way back to getting the contents of all duplicated files, programmatically.

Can Java process such duplicate files, somehow?

Or, maybe more general, is it a valid and supported situation, from specs' point of view, to have a jar with duplicate files inside? I've checked [Jar File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) and it didn't give me a clue, either.

Answer (score 2):

In `maven-shade-plugin` this is done with an [AppendingTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer).

My interpretation of the gradle plugin [documentation](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow#appending-files) you are using is that this is done this way:

```
shadowJar {
  append('META-INF/spring.factories')
}
```